# Horizontal Slide-out menu issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the link for the menu and submenu: http://mysecretathens.gr/evol/colors.html

If you click on *WORK* ,the submenu normally rolls down. But because of the slider I installed, the submenu doesn't roll as it should (slider blocks it). I thought it had something to do with the overflow: hidden element, how can this be fixed?

Note: You can see that in the *BIOGRAPHY* section the submenu works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually overriding somewhere background color of `ul` class `cbp-hssubmenu` add this in your css file:

```
.cbp-hsmenu > li.cbp-hsitem-open .cbp-hssubmenu {
    background-color: white;

}
```